# how to use javascript to handle a large html checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have something like this inside a form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="arr" value="A" />A
<input type="checkbox" name="arr" value="B" />B
<input type="checkbox" name="arr" value="C" />C
<input type="checkbox" name="arr" value="D" />D
<input type="checkbox" name="arr" value="E" />E
...
<more checkboxes here>
...
```

In my Javascript I want to create an array that consists the values of boxes that are checked. So if B and D are checked it should be `[B, D]`.

thanks

EDIT: My bad for not including a jQuery tag, but the guy who deleted his answer gave me a nice and short working solution using jQuery:

```
var valueArray = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="arr"]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: [for Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide%2FStatements#for_Statement) and [Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) supposed to be helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're using it for, it may be enough to just use `name="arr[]"`. When the form is submitted, the server-side will automatically convert the selected checkbox values to an array.

However, if you're trying to get this array purely in the client-side JavaScript, it's a little more involved. Try this:

```
function getCheckedBoxes(name) {
    if( document.querySelectorAll) {
        var qsa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][name='"+name+"']"),
            l = qsa.length, i, out = [];
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) if( qsa[i].checked) out.push(qsa[i].value);
    }
    else {
        var qsa = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), l = qsa.length, i, out = [];
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
            if( qsa[i].type == 'checkbox' && qsa[i].name == name && qsa[i].checked)
                out.push(qsa[i].value);
        }
    }
    return out;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery like this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=arr][checked]").each( 
    function() { 
       // collect the values
    } 
);
```

Comment: Do you see a jQuery tag anywhere?

Comment: He did not mention that he is not willing to use jQuery or any other kind of framework!

Comment: So you just assumed he would. How insulting.